# API Endpoint with custom query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

GET /v1/videos
[image]

Get all available video objects. Also supports

Filtering by

1.title

2.genre

3.contentRating

Sorting in descending order by

1.releaseDate (default selected)

2.viewCount

I have to implement this.

```
router.get("/",  async (req, res) => {

const title = req.body.title

const genres = req.query.genres 
const contentRating = req.query.contentRating 
let sortBy = req.query.sortBy || "releaseDate"
let sortQuery = {
   sortBy : -1
}

const filterQuery = {}
if(title != null){
   filterQuery.title = title
 }else if(genres != null){
   filterQuery.genres = genres
}else if(contentRating != null){
   filterQuery.contentRating = contentRating
}

 console.log(filterQuery , genres)

await Video.countDocuments( filterQuery)
 .then(itemCount => {
  if(itemCount == 0){
    return res.status(400).json("No video found")
  }
Video.find(filterQuery)
    .sort(sortQuery)
    .then(items => {
        return res.status(200).json(items)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting all the users', err)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "No item in the database" })
    })
})
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't use else if in this case

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc  I did that to check if requested query is available or not.
How can I improve this.
Thanks

Comment: if title query is available then your code will not apply other query

Comment: ohh.. Yeah.. got it. but the title itself is not giving the desired results.

Comment: You can use $regex: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/